# sharepoint job execute on start timer (net start sptimerv4)

Tags: timer-jobs

I have a JOB that executes on "NET Start SPTimerv4".

I dont want that my JOB execute on this actions.

Someone can tell me what I need to do ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, all Jobs are tied to SPTimerv4 service.

UPDATE: When you deploy your Job's dll, you need to restart SPTimerv4 service, so SharePoints updates job definition, therefore you need to stop SPTimerv4 and start it again. Again, as far as I know, there is no workaround this mechanic.

Comment: Yes, but not necessarily ON Start !!!

Comment: Yes,  But it occors always I restart SPTimerv4 service!!! and not just at the predefined TIME!

Comment: So, if I understands correctly, problem is your Job executes always post SPTimerv4 service restart, even if it shouldn't. Can you tell us how does your SPSchedule looks like?

Answer (score 0):

1. Timer jobs operate in the context of the SharePoint Timer Service (OWSTimer).
2. A timer job is a schedule of when to run a service by using the SharePoint Service Timer service, which is a service that runs other services according to schedules specified in timer jobs
3. You must restart the Timer service. If you just deploy the timer job without restarting Timer service, it will not take your latest updates. So always have a practice to restart the "SharePoint Timer Service" because the timer jobs code gets cached in the timer.
4. [Timer Service Recycle Job](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2012/01/10/the-timer-recycle-job-job-timer-recycle.aspx) - primary work is to restart the Timer Service by calling on the Administration Service to do so. Because many jobs written by many parties run in the same Timer Service process, one misbehaving job could cause problems for all other jobs on the same server, which could ultimately cause problems across the farm. To mitigate this risk, a job runs by default once daily at 6:00 AM to recycle the timer service.

Instead of waiting till the next 6.00 am, we are going for an immedieate recyle of Timer Service to get the latest definitions of Timer Jobs using "NET Start SPTimerv4" command.